# Race condition in ApolloProvider when using multiple clients with different authorizations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am using ApolloProvider with two authorizations, one for guests and the other for signed-in users. The default client is with the guest authorization and on sign-in, I create a new client with special specific tokens. However, queries that require user authorizations I make soon after sometimes return `401 Permission Denied` error. How can I ensure I am using the correct client for my query?

Here is some sample code:

```
const CustomApolloProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [client, setClient] = useState(getGuestClient());

  // gets called when user signs in
  const onUserSignIn = () => {
    setClient(getUserClient());
  });

  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
};
```

Another file that throws an error:

```
const [
  checkUserExists, // needs special permissions
  {
    data: checkUserExistsData,
    loading: loadingCheckUserExistsData,
    error: checkUserExistsError,
    },
] = useLazyQuery(gql(getUser), { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' });

// gets called when user signs in
const onUserSignIn = () => {
  await checkUserExists();
});
```

Comment: `checkUserExists()` will use the client that was active when the `useLazyQuery()` hook was called the last time. If the two `onUserSignIn` functions are called synchronously, it is very much expected that it's still the old client.

Comment: You can use a ref, or call `checkUserExists({client: getUserClient()})`

Comment: Are there any other common patterns? Wouldn't specifying the client for each query become tedious over time?

Comment: It's not every query, it's only the ones that you have prepared while logged out and fire exactly on the same `onUserSignIn` event that changes the client.

Comment: If you could share the full component (or at least the parts that interact with the queries and the login), I could give more detailed advice.

Comment: I only seem to be able to pass client when defining the lazyQuery, not when calling it. Maybe it's just easier to restructure the code to not call queries until later. Thanks for your help!